# Vuejs component inside component

Tags: vue.js

I have the following situation:

My page consists of several components, which all need to be shown inside some sort of modal / overlay (which I've called 'panel'). So I've made a Panel component which contains all the functionality of the panel (close, resize, move etc). Now I want to load 3-4 different components inside this panel. How would I go and do that?

I was hoping to be able to do something like this:

```
<Panel>
    <Component1></Component1>
</Panel>

<Panel>
    <Component2></Component2>
</Panel>

<Panel>
    <Component3></Component3>
</Panel>
```

But that doesn't work. So I was thinking I should somehow pass my custom components to my panel components, but I couldn't figure out how to do so..

Anyone have an idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

[Slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots) are the idiomatic way to do this.

```
Vue.component("Panel", {
  template: `<div><slot></slot></div>`
})
```

```js
console.clear()

Vue.component("Panel",{
  template:`
    <div class="panel">
      <h2>I'm a Panel</h2>
      <slot></slot>
    </div>`
})

Vue.component("Component1",{
  template:`<h3>Im Component1</h3>`
})
Vue.component("Component2",{
  template:`<h3>Im Component2</h3>`
})
Vue.component("Component3",{
  template:`<h3>Im Component3</h3>`
})

new Vue({
 el:"#app"
})
```

```css
.panel {
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <Panel>
      <Component1></Component1>
  </Panel>

  <Panel>
      <Component2></Component2>
  </Panel>

  <Panel>
      <Component3></Component3>
  </Panel>
</div>
```